# How to pass dropdown description from one component to other component, In Angular 6 Using Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, typescript

I had to get the dropdowns from DB and use them, In component A, I am able to get the List and use them in HTML using the service layer. after submitting of Component A, I have to show the description of the selected dropdown in Component B. How can I do that?

I followed [similar to this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-work-with-dropdown-in/) to get data and show in html

.ts file

```ts
statesListFromDB: any;

this.service.getStatesList().subscribe(data => { 
         this.statesListFromDB = data;
         console.log('States List is', data);
        });
```

.html (HTML Code)

```html
<div class='form-group'>
  <label for="MailingState">State</label>
  <select id="mailAddrState" class="form-control" formControlName="mailAddrState">
    <option [ngValue]="null">Select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let c of statesListFromDB" [value]="c.codeValue">{{ c.codeDesc }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow your precise use case but I just finished V1 of a typeahead dropdown component. When the user selects an option from the dropdown it emits back to the paren.

```
// typeahead html option item
...(click)="select(result)">

// typeahead controller
@Output() selectionOutput: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
...
select(contact: any) {
    this.selectionOutput.emit(contact);
}
```

Now where my typeahead is implemented (a parent component) you can watch for the selection event and call the `addTag($event)` method.

```
<label typeahead-dropdown (selectionOutput)="addTag($event)">
```

The whole thing is on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-tag-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-tags%2Finput-tags.component.html) but it's a little overkill to learn emmiting.

You can also use a service and observable to do this but that could be overkill for a simple event.